# Update DB based on Div clicked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So basically this little box section displays like recent uploads and a little status that is red for pending and green for uploaded.  Right now I made it so when I click on the first red box it will update all the red ticks to green for completed.

How can I make it so that when I click on a single red box, it will only update that tables row to green?

Each upload has an id automatically generated in the Database.

Here is a picture of the box: https://i.gyazo.com/af895f24a2f002df588ca1863f7216fa.png

I have to manually edit the table status to green in order for it to change or I click on 1 and it updates all.  I want it to only be on the specific one clicked like displayed in the photo.

Here is another example of it but using a .gif for better demonstration: https://i.gyazo.com/3e974f1a536ba37e71fcb60fc7f19c54.gif

Javascript:

```
$("#updateStatus").click(function(){
         window.location.href = 'connections/updateStatus.php';
       });
```

PHP:

```
public function redtoGreen(){
            $query2 = "UPDATE uploads SET status = 'green'";
            $this->conn->query($query2);
            header('Location: '.'../index.php');
      }
```

Comment: Use an Id Per div. Right now you are referencing all of them, would you like me to post a full example of this?

Comment: @McStuffins Yes, I know im choosing all of them but I can't figure out how I would do it for each one individually.  I have the concept in my head but lost on code. I'd appreciate it if you did

Comment: Are you using some PHP framework in your backend?

Comment: @JoseRojas I am not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AJAX for that (although it works with redirecting back and forth too...).
Do something like this instead:

```
$("#updateStatus").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "connections/updateStatus.php"
  });
});
```

For it to update only a specific row, you have to pass on the ID of the row. Your update query will just update all rows in the table to "green". You can pass the ID on as a parameter and read it in PHP with `$id = $_POST["id"]` if you posted it by:

```
$.ajax({url: "connections/updateStatus.php", method: "POST", data: { id: 4 }});
```

You can read and update it in PHP like:

```
public function redtoGreen(){
            $id = intval($_POST["id"]);
            $query2 = "UPDATE uploads SET status = 'green' WHERE id = $id";
            $this->conn->query($query2);
}
```

Another remark: consider using prepared statements for this. SQL queries like this are not good style. You'd rather want something like:

```
public function redtoGreen(){
            $id = $_POST["id"];
            $stmt = $db->prepare ("UPDATE uploads SET status = 'green' WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->execute($id);
}
```

You can also build on the ajax query to change the row color without reloading, doing something like:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "connections/updateStatus.php", 
    method: "POST", 
    data: { id: rowno },
    success: function (result) {
      $("#myrow-" + rowno).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

However, seeing that you only have one button (#updateStatus) to update ALL rows I think you have several issues with your approach here. If you have the buttons on each row, you have conflicting IDs.

To get both the rowno and the correct button references, you can define your buttons like this:

```
<button class="updateStatus" data-rowno="1"></button>
```

When building the table, you will have to put the row number where the 1 is.
Then you can do the javascript part like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".updateStatus").click(function () {
      var el = $(this);
      var rowno = el.data("rowno");
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "connections/updateStatus.php", 
            method: "POST", 
            data: { id: rowno },
            success: function (result) {
              $(el).parent().css('background-color', 'green');
            }
        });       
  });
});
```

Tested and works with HTML like

```
<table>
    <tr><td style="background-color:red;">Blah <button class="updateStatus" data-rowno="1">Update</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="background-color:red;">Blah <button class="updateStatus" data-rowno="2">Update</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="background-color:red;">Blah <button class="updateStatus" data-rowno="3">Update</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="background-color:red;">Blah <button class="updateStatus" data-rowno="4">Update</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="background-color:red;">Blah <button class="updateStatus" data-rowno="5">Update</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Im trying to get it to work, using the examples you given.

Comment: You might need to provide the HTML of your page to be more specific. Each button for each row should carry the ID of the row. You can do it like this: set a class of `.updateStatus` instead of an id updateStatus, then assign the click handler with `$(".updateStatus").click( ... );` instead. Additionally, the button elements can include a data tag to carry the row id, which can then be read inside the click handler as `$(this).data('id')`. I'll add it to my answer, this is getting too lengthy here ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  I couldnt get it to work but its most likely because my approach was terrible.  I feel like you are truly trying to help.  I'm outputting that whole upload section through php echo'ing html.  I think what I did wrong is something with it.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f209ac4fcf03a5962f8e9bc43527866c.png and https://i.gyazo.com/0c0d17c9cb1a7fcc8a1b9aec314c2a55.png

Comment: dude, I appreciate all the help today.  I couldn't get it to work with your code but it really helped me think a lot.  Someone else, specifically "Jose" had 1 line of code: "var id = $(this).attr('id');" and this bit made me just realize what I was doing wrong and bam I got it working haha.

Comment: You get the correct answer since you were first to explain to me about prepared statements, and that i shouldnt use what I was doing, and of course you put the most effort.

Comment: Glad it works for you now! Make sure you vote Jose's answer up if it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve through AJAX, sending the ID or wherever you identify your DIV, the code will be something like this:

```
$("#updateStatus").click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "connections/updateStatus.php?id="+id
  });
});
```

and at your server side

```
public function redtoGreen(){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query2 = "UPDATE uploads SET status = 'green'";
        $this->conn->query($query2);
        header('Location: '.'../index.php');
  }
```

to change of color, take a look https://jsfiddle.net/k0ye49oh/

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your SQL query to something like below. The current query will set every row for status to 'green' in the uploads table.

```
UPDATE uploads SET status = 'green' WHERE somecolumn = somevalue
```

That somevalue needs to be sent from your javascript function call, something like

```
updatestatus.php?var=somevalue
```

and use the var as $_GET['var'] on the php page.

Comment: $("#updateStatus").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "connections/updateStatus.php"
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after some thinking I figured this out.

I thought about changing the html to have divs labeled like this: `Hello1` and `Hello2`. Here is some HTML:

```
<html>
  <div id = "Hello1">

  </div>
  <div id = "Hello2">

  </div>
</html>
```

You would put the content for each clickable box that you have.

> I recommend using Jose Rojas's Javascript.

Here is some PHP to update them accordingly.

With my example, you would just using the `$_GET` global value instead of a `$_POST`

```
<?php
  $div = $_GET['div'];
  redToGreen($div);
  function redToGreen($div) {
    $query = "UPDATE uploads SET status = 'green' WHERE div = '{$div}'";
    try {
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();
      header('Location: ../index.php');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      header('Location: ../pages-500.html');
    }
  }
?>
```

If you have any questions, feel free to comment, and I will respond.

Comment: based on looking at your code, my whole approach was incorrect.  I responded to Lupinity with my full code of the html im using which is through php.

Comment: I will add more code when i get home, I am leaving now.

Comment: I appreciate the help, although I've gotten it working.